# How to fix Camera2 front face camera portrait video captured resulted rotated inverted

Tags: android, android-camera2

I am making record video app. for video recording i am following google video recording example. Rear camera resulted perfect video but when i tried to capture video with Front camera it gives inverted video result. how i can fix this problem.in some device it's camera preview also shown inverted.

here is the code of camera setup

```
 private static final int SENSOR_ORIENTATION_INVERSE_DEGREES = 270;
    private static final int SENSOR_ORIENTATION_DEFAULT_DEGREES = 90;
private static final SparseIntArray INVERSE_ORIENTATIONS = new SparseIntArray();
private static final SparseIntArray DEFAULT_ORIENTATIONS = new SparseIntArray();

static {
    INVERSE_ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_270, 0);
    INVERSE_ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_180, 90);
    INVERSE_ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_90, 180);
    INVERSE_ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_0, 270);
}

static {
    DEFAULT_ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_90, 0);
    DEFAULT_ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_0, 90);
    DEFAULT_ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_270, 180);
    DEFAULT_ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_180, 270);
}



private void openCamera(int width, int height) {
        final Activity activity = this;
        if (null == activity || activity.isFinishing()) {
            return;
        }
        CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        try {
            Log.d(TAG, "tryAcquire");
            if (!mCameraOpenCloseLock.tryAcquire(3500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Time out waiting to lock camera opening.");
            }
            /**
             * default front camera will activate
             */
        String cameraId = manager.getCameraIdList()[0];

        CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);
        StreamConfigurationMap map = characteristics
                .get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);
        mSensorOrientation = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_ORIENTATION);
        if (map == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Cannot get available preview/video sizes");
        }
        mVideoSize = chooseVideoSize(map.getOutputSizes(MediaRecorder.class));
        mPreviewSize = chooseOptimalSize(map.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class),
                width, height, mVideoSize);

        int orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
        if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            mTextureView.setAspectRatio(mPreviewSize.getWidth(), mPreviewSize.getHeight());
        } else {
            mTextureView.setAspectRatio(mPreviewSize.getHeight(), mPreviewSize.getWidth());
        }
        configureTransform(width, height);
        mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(BaseActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            requestPermission();
            return;
        }
        manager.openCamera(cameraId, mStateCallback, null);
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "openCamera: Cannot access the camera.");
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Camera2API is not supported on the device.");
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Interrupted while trying to lock camera opening.");
    }
}
```